# How to construct a graph (nodes and edges) in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, graph

I have a txt file has coordinates for multiple rectangles (X*center*, Y*center*, width, height). I would like to create an undirected graph network where the nodes of which stand for the rectangle and the edges of which represent distance between the nodes.

**txt file:**

```
 Xcenter    Ycenter     width    height
0.568396   0.394130   0.176887  0.345912
0.391509   0.393082   0.172170  0.327044
0.717571   0.377358   0.119104  0.320755
0.254717   0.373166   0.103774  0.299790
```

Comment: I recommend to you [networkx](https://networkx.org/)

Comment: How to implement it using networkx?

Comment: Perhaps you mean the distance between the rectangle centers?  Or perhaps something else?

Comment: Yes, the distance between the rectangle centers.

Comment: So, edit your question.  Specify the distance measure you want to use and remove the width, height - they are irrelevant.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to represent a node? @ravenspoint

Comment: You still have not edited your question so that it makes sense.

Comment: Try looking at [Graph Implementation in Python](https://www.techiedelight.com/graph-implementation-python/).

Answer (score 0):

In graph, you can represent rectangles as a 'list' of nodes with their x,y,height and weight as their properties, and represent their edges in an adjacency matrix, with distance between them marked in each cell.
Below is a sample program, that creates a complete-graph out of given data.

```py
import math
class node:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.height=height
        self.width=width

class graph:
    def __init__(self,txt):
        self.node_list=[]
        for line in txt.split("\n"):
            x,y,width,height=[i for i in line.strip().split(' ') if i!='']
            new_node=node(x,y,height,width)
            self.node_list.append(new_node)

        self.adjacency_matrix= self.get_adjacenty_matrix()

    def get_distance(self,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        x1=float(x1)
        y1=float(y1)
        x2=float(x2)
        y2=float(y2)
        
        dis= math.sqrt(((x2-x1)**2)+((y2-y1)**2))
        return dis

    def get_adjacenty_matrix(self):
        matrix=[]
        for i in range(len(self.node_list)):
            row=[0]*len(self.node_list)
            for j in range(len(self.node_list)):
                row[j]=self.get_distance(self.node_list[i].x, self.node_list[i].y, self.node_list[j].x, self.node_list[j].y)
            matrix.append(row)
        return matrix

txt="""0.568396   0.394130   0.176887  0.345912
0.391509   0.393082   0.172170  0.327044
0.717571   0.377358   0.119104  0.320755
0.254717   0.373166   0.103774  0.299790"""

print(graph(txt).adjacency_matrix)
```

Output (Adjacency matrix):

```
[[0.0, 0.17689010450842071, 0.15011489136324876, 0.314378759360425],
 [0.17689010450842071, 0.0, 0.3264409165836905, 0.13823421544610434], 
 [0.15011489136324876, 0.3264409165836905, 0.0, 0.46287298277173183],
 [0.314378759360425, 0.13823421544610434, 0.46287298277173183, 0.0]]
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Let's say that I have a feature list for each node stored in (.npy) file. How to assign each feature to each node?

Comment: Customize the the class `node`, as per your requirements. and assign the features to them.

Comment: I try to convert 'self.node_list' to tensor but it gives me error: TypeError: must be real number, not node